# How to get a dynamic sub-zone for Google Compute Engine Instance to overcome ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

I am using Google Cloud Compute Engine API to create VMs within my Google Cloud App Engine application as following :

```
compute.instances().insert(
        project=project,
        zone="europe-west2-b",
        body=config).execute()
```

I just started seeing the following logs in Google Cloud Logging AuditLogs :

```
2021-01-17 20:55:33.399 UTC
compute.googleapis.com
v1.compute.instances.insert
projects/supereye1/zones/europe-west2-b/instances/vm-c7fncyobtsg
supereye1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
```

How can I make a dynamic zone assigned Compute Engine instance in a particular Zone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API requires specifying the zone and does not offer "find an available zone within a region".

On failure, your code (logic) can select a different zone and try again.

A Google Cloud zone is a datacenter. Think the size of a shopping mall. Zones are located far enough apart that just arbitrarily picking a zone is not a good idea. Latency, load balancing, fault tolerance, etc should be designed considering these factors.

If you are just launching a single independent instance, then you might not care where your instance runs within a region. In that case, you will need to design zone selection and retries into your software.